# JSMPP ResponseTimeoutException: No response after waiting for 2000 millis when executing submit_sm

Tags: java, sms, sms-gateway, smpp, jsmpp

I am using JSMPP http://code.google.com/p/jsmpp/ for sending and receiving messages .It works fine when i send the short message with less than 140 characters but When i try to send the long sms, It throws the following exception:

I tried setting the TransactionTimer(3000L); it still gives me same error

Is it correct the way I am setting the optional parameters or am I doing something wrong there and this error is occuring because of that?  Could any one please let me know.

```
Response timeout
org.jsmpp.extra.ResponseTimeoutException: No response after waiting for 2000 millis when executing submit_sm with sessionId 090debe6 and sequenceNumber 2
at org.jsmpp.session.AbstractSession.executeSendCommand(AbstractSession.java:261)
at org.jsmpp.session.SMPPSession.submitShortMessage(SMPPSession.java:320)
at javaapplication1.SimpleSubmitExample.main(SimpleSubmitExample.java:99)
Caused by: org.jsmpp.extra.ResponseTimeoutException: No response after 3000 millis
at org.jsmpp.extra.PendingResponse.waitDone(PendingResponse.java:117)
at org.jsmpp.session.AbstractSession.executeSendCommand(AbstractSession.java:257)
... 2 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using Ozeki Smpp sms gateway lite and they have fixed this problem in their latest verison.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this issue by setting 10000L as timeout delay. 2 or 3s is too short if your session has to treat DELIVERY_SM when SUBMIT SM transaction is initiated.

Comment: Old question, but how did you set that?